# textbox visible dependiendo del valor de una lista despegable

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hola como estan el problema que tengo es como hacer que un texbox sea visible dependiedno del valor de una lista depegable,

adjunto el codigo de la vista

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Proyecto Empresa | Usuarios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
.contenido{
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url('usuarios')?>">Usuarios</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Operaciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Reportes Mensual</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reportes Anual</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mantenimiento<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a  href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#contact">Indicadores</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Cuadro de Mando</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?= $this->session->userdata('name')?><b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cerrar"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

<section class="contenido">
<div class="row">



<div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">

                <br>
<div class="row">
<div id="listaEmpleados" class="col-lg-8">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

<form id="form-actualizar" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>usuarios/guardar" method="POST" role="form" style="padding:0 10px;">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

                       echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$categoria.'</option>';
                     }

                    ?>
                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>



<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Estado de curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="estado" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="1" >Planeado</option>
                        <option value="2">Eljecutado</option>

                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ejemplo_email_1">N de desertores</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deser" >
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ejemplo_password_1">N de facilitadores</label>

<?php 

if ($datos==="Autoestudio") {
?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facil"  value="N/A" disabled >
<?php

} else {
?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facil"  >
<?php
}


 ?>


  </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnactualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Guardar</button>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>


</div>

</section>

</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/usuarios.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

por ejemplo quiero que cuando este el combo seleccionado en autoestudio se desabilite el textbox numero de facilitadores.asi como en el ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Avance un poco ...

Aqui esta la vista que va a quedar

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Proyecto Empresa | Usuarios</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
.contenido{
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Intergrupo</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url('usuarios')?>">Usuarios</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Operaciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Reportes Mensual</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reportes Anual</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mantenimiento<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a  href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#contact">Indicadores</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Cuadro de Mando</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?= $this->session->userdata('name')?><b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cerrar"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

<section class="contenido">
<div class="row">



<div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">

                <br>
<div class="row">
<div id="listaEmpleados" class="col-lg-8">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

<form id="form-actualizar" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>usuarios/guardar" method="POST" role="form" style="padding:0 10px;">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control" class="Categorias">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

                       echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$categoria.'</option>';
                     }

                    ?>
                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>



<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Estado de curso:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="estado" class="form-control" id="estado">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="1" >Planeado</option>
                        <option value="2">Eljecutado</option>

                    </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$(".Categorias").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var _form=$(".form-actualizar");
$.ajax({
url:base_url+'usuarios/getModalidad',
type:'POST',
dataType:'json',
data:_form.serializeArray(),

})
.done(function(response){




})



})





})



                </script>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ejemplo_email_1">N de desertores</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deser" >
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ejemplo_password_1">N de facilitadores</label>

<?php 

if ($datos==="Autoestudio") {
?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facil"  value="N/A" disabled >
<?php

} else {
?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facil"  >
<?php
}


 ?>


  </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnactualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Guardar</button>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>


</div>

</section>

</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/usuarios.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

**aqui esta el modelo**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usuarios_model extends CI_Model {

  function guardar($data){

    $this->db->insert("cmi_curs_regi", $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }

  }

  public function get_categorias(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_MODA,NOM_MODA FROM cmi_moda');


    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $datos[($row->COD_MODA)] = $row->NOM_MODA;


}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $datos;



}



      public function getModalidad($consulta){

   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT NOM_MODA FROM cmi_moda where COD_MODA=.$consulta.');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $datos[($row->NOM_MODA)] ;


}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $datos;
        var_dump($datos);


    }




}
```

**Aqui esta el controlador**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Usuarios extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');

    }
                public function index(){

                  $data['datos'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_categorias();

                  $this->load->view('frontend/usuarios',$data);

                 }

            public function guardar(){

            $estado = $this->input->post("estado");
            $deser = $this->input->post("deser");
            $facil = $this->input->post("facil");
            $categorias = $this->input->post("Categorias");


            $data = [
            "EST_CURS_REGI"=>$estado,   
            "NUM_DESE"=>$deser,
            "NUM_FACI"=>$facil ,
            "CMI_MODA_COD_MODA" =>$categorias];

            //print_r ($data);

                if ($this->Usuarios_model->guardar($data) == true) {
                    //redirect('usuarios');
                }




        }



            public function getModalidad(){

            $_name=$this->input->post('Categorias');
            $consulta = [
            "CMI_MODA_COD_MODA" =>$categorias];

        if ($this->Usuarios_model->guardar($data) == true) {
                    return $datos;
                echo    var_dump($datos);
                }


        }



}
```

Mi estrategia es como solo voy a querer esos datos de esa parte envio esa parte del formulario por ajax que pase al controlador y que le haga la consulta al modelo estara bien?

Funciona de esta manera

```
<script >

$(function(){
                $("#Categorias").on('change',function(e){

                  if($("#Categorias").val()==="1"){
                  $("#prueba1").attr("disabled",true); 
                  $("#prueba1").val("N/A");

                  }else{

                    $("#prueba1").attr("disabled",false);
                    $("#prueba1").val("");

                  }


})

});



                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres lograr se puede hacer con javascript directamente, o mas fácil con jquery, a continuación te dejo un ejemplo básico, puedes acoplarlo a tus necesidades:

```js
$("#prueba").change(function(){
  
  if($("#prueba").val()==="-1"){
    $("#prueba1").prop("disabled",false); //Esta linea sirve si solo quieres deshabilitar la entrada de texto
    $("#prueba1").val("");
    //$("#prueba1").show(); //Esta linea sirve si quieres ocultar el input text
  }else{
    $("#prueba1").prop("disabled","disabled");
    $("#prueba1").val("Deshabilitado");
    //$("#prueba1").hide();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ocultar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="prueba" id="prueba">
    <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="0">Cero</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="prueba1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: es que el valor de los combos estan siendo cargados desde base de datos

Comment: me funciono con tu codigo, lo modifique un poquito pero funciona <script >
       
$(function(){
    $("#Categorias").on('change',function(e){

      if($("#Categorias").val()==="1"){
      $("#prueba1").attr("disabled",true); 
      $("#prueba1").val("N/A");
      
       }else{

        $("#prueba1").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#prueba1").val("");
       
      }
  

})

});



      </script>

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :-), esa era la idea, que lo implementes de acuerdo a tu necesidad.